# ODP.NET with WCF

Tags: oracle, odp.net

I am getting this error when I try to use my WCF service (I am using .NET 4.5 Framework with the latest Oracle.DataAccess for .NET 4.5):

> The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or
>   is not valid.

I am on a Windows 8 box. It works fine when my endpoint address points to my localhost, but when my address points to an IIS application on my Windows 8 box I get the error.

Comment: Is there anything valuable when you [enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx)?

Comment: Where does the error occur? On the server or on the client side? And please add the configuration (app.config, web.config) file for the side where the error occurs.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with WCF

Comment: Did you verify that your IIS endpoint (not iis express) allows 32bit applications? perhaps your install of odp.net is 32bit, running on a 64bit machine, and it won't load odp.net 32bit if it's not enabled in IIS.